# View events and their parameters in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

Is it possible to view / query the raw events from my Google Analytics (gtag.js) database?
I make sure to [send additional parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#custom-parameters) with my events and have no idea where I can access those parameters.

Am I missing something? Cause can't see anything documented...

Comment: Are you talking about the event action and event label parameters, or custom dimensions? You can see the former under Behaviour -> Events.

Comment: I mean the custom parameters that you can pass along with an event:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#custom-parameters

Comment: Did you set them up in google analytics first? See [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets)

Comment: @Confuzing sounds like a good idea. Looking into it...

Comment: @mllm did you ever figure out where this is displayed in GA user interface? I can't find anything about it, but we are sending in custom params for our events.

Comment: 2020 and still can't find an answer to this :/

Comment: 2021 and still looking for an answer to this, I heavily invested in events parameters but not sure how to show them and utilize them in my reports

Comment: 2022 and still looking for an answer to this, I'm starting a bounty

Comment: @Magoo can you be a little more clear as to what you are looking for?  Do you want the Google analytics api or something?  gtag.js is just javascript its not a database.   The data is stored in Google analytics.

Comment: @DaImTo I want to add parameters to a custom event and have them searchable on the GA dashboard website. gtag.js hasn't got anything to do with GA on iOS... or does it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to set up your own custom report...
To get the parameters / reports for free, you need to use their recommended events.

[https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en#:~:text=Custom%20events%20are%20events%20that,custom%20reports%20for%20meaningful%20analysis](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en#:%7E:text=Custom%20events%20are%20events%20that,custom%20reports%20for%20meaningful%20analysis)

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735

This answer is a work in progress

This is how you create a custom report

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Maybe dumping the data into Big Query is the answer though... GA is never going to work the way engineers expect it to.. it's more high level.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Analytics event anatomy only allow:

Event Category
Event Action
Event Label
Event Value (Optional)

If you need to add more "fields" you can use Custom Dimensiones, the first step was create in the Google Analytics property. Admin -> Property -> Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions.

Later when you want to see this values you can go to the events (Behavior -> Events -> Top Events) and add and the secondary dimension taht you want to see in the event.

[Secondary dimension in events view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVEPe.png)

Comment: This answer needs more detail, I don't see the `Admin -> Property -> Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions` path nor the `Behavior -> Events -> Top Events` path.. I am completely new to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Once you navigate to the "Custom definitions" area as shown in the image, add the parameter names you want to track. So for instance, if my gtag looks like this:

gtag('event','click',{'my_custom_parameter': 'some_value'});

then put my_custom_parameter as the Event parameter. Add the Dimension name how you want it to appear in reports and make the scope "Event" and leave whatever description you want. The important part is the Event parameter matches your gtag. Make a new custom dimension for each new parameter you want to track.

In case it's not clear, the click path should be: Admin > custom definitions > Create custom dimension

Sometimes the interface changes so just explore till you find it if its different by the time you read this.

[image]